# WCF method that can take any class object as parameter

Tags: c#, wcf

```
public interface ICommunicationLoggService
{
    [OperationContract]
     bool SaveLog(Employee emp);
}
```

I need the above method as generic so that it can take the any class object as a paramter not for specific Employee object.

Like I have 3 Classes

```
class Employee
{

}
class Student
{

}
class Address
{

}
```

Now when I will call the `saveLog()` then it should take based on class..

I am not good in english hope any one will understand the question and provide me the solution..

Comment: generics would work. Or maybe an Interface, if you only need to log certain in-common properties of the entities. Depends what you need.

Comment: how about 
bool SaveLog<T>(T emp);
or 
bool SaveLog<T>(T emp) where T : class;

Comment: Best thing is to create a base class and inherit all these 3 classes from that. And have `SaveLog` method accepting the base class.

Answer (score 3):

### Update

After some research, i came to the conclusion that it seems to be the best option for [SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) to not use generics in these interfaces.

So the easiest solution seems to have a separate log method for each entity type.

```
public interface ICommunicationLoggService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool SaveLog(Employee emp);
    [OperationContract]
    bool SaveLog(Studend emp);
    [OperationContract]
    bool SaveLog(Address emp);
}
```

### Option 2

You could also use a bass class for your "loggable" types.

```
public interface ICommunicationLoggService {
  [OperationContract]
  bool SaveLog(Loggable loggable);
}

public class ComunicationLoggerService : ICommunicationLoggService {
  public bool SaveLog(Loggable loggable) {
    return false;
  }
}

public class Loggable { }

public class Employee : Loggable { }

public class Studend : Loggable { }

public class Address : Loggable { }

public class Example 
{
  public void Foo() 
  {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    ICommunicationLoggService loggService = new ComunicationLoggerService();
    loggService.SaveLog(employee);
  }
}
```

### Old Part

<del>You can use generics to achieve the desired behavior.</del>
You shouldn't use generics in WCF. I have not realized that in the first place.

Thanks to [Camilo Terevinto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141621/camilo-terevinto) for the explanation, why using a generic is bad:

> The problem is the [WSDL](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_wsdl.asp). You cannot serialize a type that you don't
>   know of

```
public interface ICommunicationLoggService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool SaveLog<TEntity>(TEntity emp);
}
```

Comment: Mmmm. That won't work, given that it is a WCF service

Comment: How would get to know that which class object is being passed.. as entity..

Comment: @KAMALVERMA You could check the type. It would be easier if the classes would share a base class or interface. If they did, you could use [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto oh generics don't work with wcf interfaces? Or do they need to have constraints on classes, so no interfaces are passed?

Comment: Actually I need a SaveLog() service method which can save the log for different-2 objects..

Comment: @TobiasTheel The problem is the WSDL. You cannot serialize a type that you don't know of

Comment: Actual i tried yesterday the same you have mentioned    [OperationContract]
    bool SaveLog(Employee emp);
    [OperationContract]
    bool SaveLog(Studend emp);

    [OperationContract]
    bool SaveLog(Address emp); but was able to solve the problem..

Comment: If I will go with option2 then i have to pass the respective class object while calling the SaveLog() or Logable class object..

Comment: I have added an example class with the example usage

Comment: Your welcome, if i could answer your question i'd be glad if you mark the answer as "accepted answer" :)

Comment: as client application I am not able to make the object of Employee or Employee class is not there I already updated the service

Comment: Could you explain that problem in more detail?

Comment: I need a WCF service with SaveLog() method which consumed by other app while consuming SaveLog() I have to pass the object of either Emp Student or Address... but while define the Iservice interface in wcf I have to write Savelog(that can take any class object..)